# Problems Creating Dissolve Card Effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a jquery novice trying to code a card like animation that dissolves to the back when click and back to the front when clicked again. I tried to do this by overlaying two divs and listening for clicks on the bottom div (essentially clicking through top div).

I was nearly successful using jQuery's fadeTo method. I could get the div on top to fade out, but not fade in again. I think the problem lies in fadeTo messing with my visibility value because now clicking the div only fires the `vizValue==visible` condition. However, my visibility property does not show up in my console so I can't check it. I appreciate your experienced eyes!

[image]
So the green div is of class `tabReveal`. I am clicking thru it to the white div of class `tab`.

html

```
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="tabReveal"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.tab{
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    pointer-events:auto;    
}

.tabReveal{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

js

```
$(document).on("click",".tab",function(){
    var vizValue = $(this).children().css("visibility");
    if (vizValue=="visible"){
        console.log("invisible cloak");
        $(this).children().fadeTo(500,0,function(){
            $(this).children().css("visibility","hidden");
            $(this).children().css("pointer-events","none");//need to reset this
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("visible cloak");
        $(this).children().fadeTo(500,100,function(){
            $(this).children().css("visibility","visible");
        })
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used opacity instead of visibility:

```
$(document).on("click",".tab",function(){
    var vizValue = $(this).children().css("opacity");
    if (vizValue==1){
        console.log("invisible cloak");
        $(this).children().fadeTo(500,0,function(){});
    }
    else {
        console.log("visible cloak");
        $(this).children().fadeTo(500,1,function(){});
    }

})
```